# Transfer data from one Jframe to another jframe using static class or this reference(Eclipse)?

Tags: java

I have one jFrame and its have one jTextbox and a button. Another jFrame have a single jLabel. I want to bring out the text written in first frame's textbox to second frame's jLabel when button is pressed. And as i have searched about this than i got some unreliable answers. But as per my knowledge it could be done by creating another static class or by calling this reference.  And I've created the frame like this in initialize function 
Frame= newJframe() 
And I'm working on Eclipse

Comment: pass text to next frame .`new frameb(text)`

Comment: Hint: if you really don't understand how to get one string ouf of a text field into another UI component ... that somehow says: you still have a lot of things to learn about java. My recommendation: forgot about UI programming for the moment. There is really no sense in trying to learn java ... and trying to get into UI programming at the same time. That is like you want to learn to juggle whilst learning to ride the unicycle at the same time. So: learn about java basics, and then turn towards advanced topics.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly: yes, you could use a static class that stores a lot of information that both the jFrame w/ textbox and jFrame with label can access directly, but this seems to foreshadow bad design. You could alternatively have a method inside your jFrame that is public so that your second jFrame can call it and fetch the text inside the textbox.

You may want to start reading about the [object-oriented model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/) and then move onto the GUI stuff (would recommend you start with that [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/)).